# Running a script with top command in the background

Tags: linux, bash, top-command

I have a script that basically prints that output of `top -n1` to a file every second

In its simplest form:

```
while [ 1 ] ; do
   top -n1
   sleep 1
done
```

If I run my secript like:

```
./my_script.sh > out.log
```

it runs fine

If I run it in the background:

```
./my_script.sh > out.log &
```

Then it give me `Stopped(SIGTTOU)` error. From other Q/As I found that top is trying to read from the stdin, and when run in the background there is no stdin.

How can I achieve logging of top into a file as a background task?

Comment: Have you tried `< /dev/null`?

Comment: @melpomene No, is that inside the script? - I am not quite sure where to put that code snippet? - thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write top to file, and that in a loop..

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ] ; do
   top -b -n 1 > top.txt
   sleep 1
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  top -b -n 1 > top.txt
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Surely you mean `#! /bin/bash` :p

Comment: `[ 1 ]` is weird way to write `true`.

Comment: @code_fodder Then why not just use `:`? Can't get much shorter than `while :; do ...`. Also, `true` is actually shorter than `[ 1 ]` by one character.

Comment: @melpomene damn... even better  :))

Comment: Or the equivalent of while true: `until false; do stuff; done`